# ComboBox.Value gives me an "Error 380" Invalid Property value

Tags: excel, vba

I've had this userform working for months and all of a sudden it starts giving me this error! Its a very simple userform with 2 comboboxes. A different macro calls the userform, and shows it to the user asking for the user to select a value from each of the lists, and then the userform hides itself and the macro resumes.

For whatever reason, the ComboBox is throwing an error when I try `.Value = myVar`. It doesn't make any sense to me. The error is "Run-time error '380': Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value." but `Value` *is* a valid property of the ComboBox!!

Here's the sub where I have the error:

```vb
Private Sub UserDisambiguation(ByRef CustomerName As String, ByRef Division As String)
    With CustomerSelectionForm
        .Company.Value = CustomerName '<----- ERROR?!?!
        .Division.Value = Division
        .Show
        CustomerName = .Company.Value
        Division = .Division.Value
    End With
    
    Unload CustomerSelectionForm
End Sub
```

This is in a Code Module in the same workbook as the userform `CustomerSelectionForm`. The two ComboBoxes are `Company` and `Division`. At the time of the error `CustomerName` is a valid string, and is a valid option present in `Company.List`.

---

An example execution:

User starts the macro with some values

`CompanyName` = "Orange"

`Division` = "Peel"

Macro detects multiple entries matching the data, asks for Disambiguation, presents the user with options:

"Orange"

"Mandarin Orange"

"Navel Orange"

User is shown their current data "Orange", uses the combobox to select a valid option, and presses "OK". The `UserDisambiguation` sub passes the corrected values back into the variables and wipes the userform.

---

Excel 2007 12.0.4518.1014
Microsoft Visual Basic 6.5.1020

Answer (score 2):

The `ComboBox.Style` had accidentally been changed from `fmStyleDropDownCombo` to `fmStyleDropDownList`. This prevented any values from being filled into the ComboBox and only allowed selections to be made using the `List`.

It is working now that I have changed it back.

I was disappointed to not find any answers regarding this ComboBox error, so I am choosing to answer my own question and leave it up rather than wipe away my shame by deleting the question.